# NHibernate stateless session - unable to load, update and save object due to reference property

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm working on some code that is doing some moderately heavy data processing with NHibernate (yes, I know, perhaps not really the right tool for the job. But it's what I've got to work with)

I use a stateless session to get the first 1000 objects, check, update and add them to a list of updated objects if needed.
I then repeat for the next 1000 objects until I'm done. Below is a significantly simplified version of the code.

```
List<MarketOrder> updated = new List<MarketOrder>();
IStatelessSession session = SessionProvider();
int offset = 0;
bool moreToGet = true;

while (moreToGet)
{
    var result = session.Query<MarketOrder>().Where(o => o.Owner.ID == currentEntityID && !o.Updated);
    var tmp = result.Skip(offset).Take(1000);

    foreach (MarketOrder item in data) 
    { 
        notUpdated.OrderState = MarketOrderState.Closed;
        updated.Add(notUpdated);
    }

    if (data.Count == pageSize) { offset += pageSize; }
    else { moreToGet = false; }
}
```

Another stateless session is then opened to do a bulk update

```
IStatelessSession session = SessionProvider();
foreach (MarketOrder o in updated) { session.Update(o); }
```

When I run my unit test, I get an error:

```
Test 'TestProcess_AutoCloseOrder' failed: NHibernate.PropertyValueException : Error         dehydrating property value for Data.Models.MarketOrder.Owner
---- NHibernate.PropertyAccessException : Exception occurred getter of Common.Models.ModelBase.Version
-------- System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
------------ NHibernate.SessionException : proxies cannot be fetched by a stateless session
```

After some messing around, I figured that the error is because, in the Update, NHibernate is trying to access the `Owner` property of the `MarketOrder` being saved. (I assume this is to cascade the update)
`Owner` is populated with a proxy and since it was loaded from a stateless session, cannot be accessed.

Sure enough, if I load from a regular session instead of a stateless session it all works fine. This solution will result in a performance hit in production though so I'd rather avoid it.

I could set `Owner` to not lazy load but that is not a practical solution for all similar cases.

The answer to this question: [NHibernate: proxies cannot be fetched by a stateless session error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143609/nhibernate-proxies-cannot-be-fetched-by-a-stateless-session-error-message). Suggests fetching the problem property as part of the initial load but that seems very wasteful. I only want to update a few properties on the main object, why should I have to load all that object's child references as well?

What I want is for NHibernate to realise that only the main `MarketOrder` object has changed and not bother to cascade the update to `Owner`. In fact, now I think about it, I didn't think Stateless Session was supposed to cascade updates at all?

So anyone know what's going on here and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Can you FETCH owner in the first query? e.g. `session.Query<MarketOrder>().Fetch(f => f.Owner).Where` ...

Comment: Yes, I just don't see why that should be necessary. It seems like an excessive overhead to fetch all my referenced objects just to change one or two simple properties on the main object.

Comment: Like it or not it may be your only solution if you want to stick with multiple sessions.

Comment: I wonder if on second query just before update you can do `o.Owner = session.Load<Owner>(o.Owner.Id);` as the `o.Owner.Id` will be available at this point and shouldn't force a proxy initialise.

Comment: I tried just using a single session for load and update but still get the same problem. Perhaps I'm not being clear enough - I don't want to load this other entity. I shouldn't have to. If that's just the way NHibernate is then ok but I'm thinking I must just have it wrong since it seems remarkably odd to be forced to load entities that you're not going to do anything with.

Comment: Do you use versioning? Is this the cause of the error message

Comment: I do use versioning. (simple int column that I let NHibernate handle) Surely if that was the problem then loading with a regular session would not have fixed it?

Comment: Does `MarketOrder` have a custom `Equals` or `GetHashCode` method that references `Owner`?

Comment: @DanielSchilling No, it only has a `Clone` method